# ng-disabled not working with $scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying something like this -

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-section"
     ng-disabled="{{ selectedfruits.length }} < 5" > Show selected fruits</button>
```

In chrome developers tool the source looks like this

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-section" 
    ng-disabled="0 < 5">
        Show selected fruits</button>
```

But the button is not disabled,my controller looks like this -

```
.controller('fruitSelectorController',
     function ($scope, $rootScope, $timeout) { 
    $scope.fruits = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
                $scope.selectedfruits = [];
    });
```

Comment: No need to parse the variables in angular's directives

Comment: just remove the {{}} from ng-disabled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to write without interpolation `{{ }}`. It will automatically parse the content and use the expression

```
ng-disabled="selectedfruits.length < 5"
```

See the [**Documentation**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)

Answer (score 5):

You should remove the curly braces from ng-disabled.
No need evaluate the array in the view HTML.
The scope variable automatically evaluated and angular has great feature which is two way binding, so automatically view will be updated.

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-section" ng-disabled=" selectedfruits.length  < 5" > Show selected fruits</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="fruitSelectorController">
<button ng-disabled="selectedfruits.length  < 5">Test</button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('fruitSelectorController', function ($scope) 
    { 
        $scope.fruits = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
        $scope.selectedfruits = ['1'];
    });
</script>
</html>
```